# GCC cross-toolchain for ARM

Tags: gcc, compilation

I am following steps given [here](http://frank.harvard.edu/~coldwell/toolchain/)
But I am getting failures at different stages.

Following are the different stages in building cross compiler.

1. Setup
2. Get the sources
3. GNU binutils
4. Linux Kernel Headers
5. Glibc headers
6. Stage 1 GCC
7. GNU C Library
8. Stage 2 GCC

Error-1:(occurred at stage 5)- Critical section of programs are missed or old:as and ld

Solution: I edited the configure script for glibc, and changed these lines

```
case $ac_prog_version in
'') ac_prog_version="v. ?.??, bad"; ac_verc_fail=yes;;
2.1[3-9]*)
ac_prog_version="$ac_prog_version, ok"; ac_verc_fail=no;;
*) ac_prog_version="$ac_prog_version, bad"; ac_verc_fail=yes;;

case $ac_prog_version in
'') ac_prog_version="v. ?.??, bad"; ac_verc_fail=yes;;
2.1[3-9]*)
ac_prog_version="$ac_prog_version, ok"; ac_verc_fail=no;;
*) ac_prog_version="$ac_prog_version, bad"; ac_verc_fail=yes;;
```

to this:

```
case $ac_prog_version in
'') ac_prog_version="v. ?.??, bad"; ac_verc_fail=yes;;
2.2[0-9]*)
ac_prog_version="$ac_prog_version, ok"; ac_verc_fail=no;;
*) ac_prog_version="$ac_prog_version, bad"; ac_verc_fail=yes;;

case $ac_prog_version in
'') ac_prog_version="v. ?.??, bad"; ac_verc_fail=yes;;
2.2[0-9]*)
ac_prog_version="$ac_prog_version, ok"; ac_verc_fail=no;;
*) ac_prog_version="$ac_prog_version, bad"; ac_verc_fail=yes;;
```

It got resolved.

```
Error 2:(occurred at stage 6)
*** buffer overflow detected ***: arm-unknown-linux-gnu-ar terminated
```

Can anyone faced the similar kind of problem? if so can you please suggest the solution?

Comment: its unlikely to get an answer with 0% accepted rate.